# Collapsing steps in HTML output of Cucumber

Tags: html, ruby, cucumber

When making output for cucumber scenarios using the default html formatter, you can easily collapse on the scenarios level. I would also want to have the ability to collapse or expand output of specific steps the same way I can do with whole scenarios. How can i do it? Probably by overriding default html with custom formatter, but any tip on how to achieve that?